# ¿Cómo se usa rebind<>::other de la plantilla Allocator en los diferentes contenedores de stl (list, vector, map, set, ...)?

Tags: c++, manejo-de-memoria, contenedores

La plantilla Allocator es una "interfaz" que describe cómo se administra la memoria de los objetos que queremos guardar. Las funciones más importantes de dicha plantilla son allocate, deallocate, construct y destroy. Pero una de las cosas que más me chocaban era la estructura rebind:

```
template<class T>
struct allocator{

    //...

    template<typename U>
    struct rebind{
        typedef allocator<U> other;
    }

    //...

}
```

En esta [entrada](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14148756/what-does-template-rebind-do) de stackoverflow se explica un poco para qué sirve esto. Si he entendido bien, en la clase `std::list<type,alloc<type>>` se usa `alloc<type>` para crear los objetos de tipo type. Además la lista necesita de nodos (digamos objetos de tipo `node<type>`) para almacenar dichos objetos, por lo que para crear dichos nodos hará uso de la clase `alloc<node<type>>`. Pero para conseguir esa clase es necesario usar el rebind:

```
class list<typename type, class Alloc>{

    //...

    /*En la definición de la clase se tiene Alloc, que es una clase para 
      proporcionar objetos de tipo type.*/

    /*Si suponemos que "Alloc == Allocator<type>" entonces necesitamos
      Allocator<node<type>> para crear los nodos. Esto lo conseguimos
      con rebind.*/

    typename Alloc::template rebind<node<type>>::other allocatorDeNodos;

    //...

}
```

Por otro lado, tengo entendido que la clase std::vector no utiliza nodos. ¿Utiliza rebind de alguna forma? ¿Cómo lo usa? ¿Cómo lo hacen el resto de contenedores?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La implementación de los diferentes contenedores de la STL es libre. El estándar solo contempla la interfaz de dichos contenedores.

Dicho esto, la clase `Alloc` que comentas es una generalización pensada para funcionar en todas las situaciones. Esto quiere decir que es perfectamente posible que haya contenedores no necesiten aprovechar todo el potencial de esta plantilla... todo depende de las necesidades específicas del contenedor.

Por tanto, es altamente probable que `vector` **no haga uso** de `rebind`... aunque eso no quita que alguna implmentación sí haga uso de esta característica. Para saberlo te toca revisar la implementación de dicho contenedor (que recordemos puede variar entre compiladores).